# Create library like jQuery style

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var jQuery = function( selector ) {
    return new jQuery.fn.init( selector );
};

jQuery.fn = jQuery.prototype = {...};

var init = jQuery.fn.init = function( selector ){
    this.selector   = selector;
    this.element    = document.querySelector(this.selector);
};

console.log(
    jQuery('div').selector
);
```

I'm currently study how jQuery works, but I got few questions

1. `jQuery.fn = jQuery.prototype = {};` why `prototype = object`, isn't prototype usually come with name after `jQuery.prototype.foo = function...`
2. `var init = jQuery.fn.init (jQuery.prototoype.init)` when I remove `var init`, i got an error, like this : `var jQuery.fn.init = ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1) jQuery.fn = jQuery.prototype = {}; why prototype = object**

Actually, prototype is an object only when you do something like,

```
**jQuery.prototype.get = function(){
 //Code
}**
```

You are actually creating a member function in prototype object only with name "get". You could have done it like this also as:

```
**jQuery.prototype = {
  "get" : function(){
  }
}**
```

**2) When you remove init, the statement becomes as var jQuery.fn.init = ...**

Actually this is not a valid statement because jQuery object is already available. It is a syntactical error. You cannot create a member of any object like this.
For that, you just need to do as

```
**jQuery.fn.init = function(){
}**
```

Comment: is jQuery.fn.init = jQuery.prototype.init? is this relate to jQuery.prototype ={} object?

Answer (score 1):

1. Setting the prototype to be an empty object clears every left-over
   from the JavaScript side and makes it a completely new "class" or
   object.
2. When you remove the `var`-part, you basically remove the complete
       definition. A variable name cannot contain dots, because a dot by
       definition requires an object. Therefore, `var a.b.c = 1` will not
       be valid. You need to have an object `a = { b: {} }` and then do
       `a.b.c = 1`.